# Header is received by Apache, but not present in php

Tags: php, apache, http, rest, cpanel

I came across a very weird issue.

I'm using postman to send HTTP requests for some rest service i wrote in PHP. I've been testing it in my development server without any issue. And then it was ready to go to production server. After deploy, I noticed i couldn't authenticate. I'm using Basic HTTP Authentication over SSL.

After digging into it, i noticed the header wasn't reaching my code. A var_dump(apache_request_headers()), didn't show "Authorization" header, but then i enabled mod_forensic, and recorded that same request. The header was set in forensic_log, but isn't set in php headers.

I'm on Cpanel/WHM, Apache/2.4.9, PHP 5.5.10. Also tested with Apache 2.2.x and php 5.4.x in the same server.

There is a copy of the request:

```
+Uyw0q60sJjwAAFodDcIAAAAC|GET /pt_BR/webservice/product HTTP/1.1|Host:www.website.com.br|Connection:keep-alive|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36|Cache-Control:no-cache|Content-Type:application/json|Authorization:Basic Zmhjc0BsaXZlLmNvbTo2NzY2MTI1NTEzNjcxOTQxMjEzNjgxMDcxMDg2MDcwNA==|Postman-Token:e87e4305-08b8-6868-69d6-9132ff741f6f|Accept:*/*|Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch|Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4
```

and the var_dump(apache_request_headers()):

```
array(10) {
  ["Content-Type"]=>
  string(16) "application/json"
  ["Accept"]=>
  string(3) "*/*"
  ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
  string(17) "gzip,deflate,sdch"
  ["Accept-Language"]=>
  string(35) "en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4"
  ["Cache-Control"]=>
  string(8) "no-cache"
  ["Connection"]=>
  string(10) "keep-alive"
  ["Cookie"]=>
  string(42) "PHPSESSID=a00f255f7e96b25f34f84670fbb8362e"
  ["Host"]=>
  string(21) "www.website.com.br"
  ["Postman-Token"]=>
  string(36) "b1d04f7f-89b3-e7fd-3841-9850f5ff1916"
  ["User-Agent"]=>
  string(105) "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your production server is running PHP as FastCGI?

Referencing a FAQ page of a [German hoster](http://uberspace.de/dokuwiki/webserver%3afastcgi) there exists an inconsistency in naming the concerned http variable in this case.

This mod_rewrite rule should fix this issue then:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

If you are running PHP as apache2 module, this does not help.

Comment: The options i have are, suphp, dso, cgi and none. Currently set to suphp.

Comment: With suphp the PHP_AUTH_USER header is only set if the inferred targetmode is PHP. This can be accomplished by configuring [x-httpd-php=php\:/usr/bin/php](http://www.suphp.org/DocumentationView.html?file=CONFIG) (instead of the other configuration variant), but likely you do not have access to the suphp configuration? You might mail your hoster and ask them for assistance. Otherwise suphp should pass the HTTP headers on, I just checked their source code. Instead you can try it with DSO or CGI(maybe with the rewrite rule) nevertheless, to see if it's working that way.

Comment: Its a dedicated server. I have access to everything.

With dso i got some other problems, while with cgi the result was the same.

Where can i see the value for that x-httpd-php?

Also, the rewrite rule didn't solve it.

Comment: "The suPHP configuration file resides in $sysconfdir/suphp.conf (which will resolve e.g. to /etc/suphp.conf)." and "In the [handlers] section you specify a mapping between mime-types and interpreters to be used." This section should be modified, if it says `x-httpd-php=execute:!self` instead of `x-httpd-php=php\:/usr/bin/php`.

Comment: /home/cpeasyapache/src/suphp.conf
[handlers]
;Handler for php-scripts
application/x-httpd-php="php:/usr/bin/php"
application/x-httpd-php4="php:/usr/php4/bin/php"
application/x-httpd-php5="php:/usr/bin/php"

;Handler for CGI-scripts
;x-suphp-cgi="execute:!self"

Comment: And your apache configuration contains something like `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`? By the way, you are just checking `apache_request_headers()`. Might it be, that although the function does not list the http header, that `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` is set? I do not know how `apache_request_headers` behaves behind suphp.

Comment: You were right, the user/pw is set in $_SERVER, but not in apache_request_headers(). Is anything I can do to fix that? I mean get apache_request_headers to work properly.

Comment: I claim you won't get happy on this path. suphp calls `ap_add_common_vars` of apache to prepare the environment for the process which actually runs your php script. I did not look up the current apache2 source code, but in apache 1.3 [the function does not set authorization headers](http://pedrowa.weba.sk/docs/ApiDoc/apidoc_ap_add_common_vars.html). A few lines further it checks the remaining headers for authorization headers, but only puts them into the environment. Inside the new process it parses those, and sets the php environment variables. No http headers are being set.